# Minimongo memory consumption

Tags: meteor, minimongo

I have collection with size about 30 MB (on server). It's fully mirrored with client. Tell me, why client uses hundreds of ram (400MB+) instead of 30 MB? I was searching for minimongo memory efficiency, but I found nothing, so I'm asking now

Comment: Could you post code to support your claim? Something that would for example populate a collection with 30MB worth of data on the server.

Comment: Probably because it's using a browser and browsers take up memory. Consider using `{ limit: <somelimit> }` on your publication for more memory efficiency

Comment: To determine the page overhead, subscribe to nothing and look at the memory usage then subscribe to everything and measure the difference. Browsers tend to be memory hogs. After a few hours a facebook page can easily grow over 1GB for example.